# rails custom_configuration gem produces empty orderedoptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Ruby 2.1.5
Rails 4.0.13

Using the [custom_configuration gem](https://github.com/dhh/custom_configuration/issues/4), I get unexpected results.

config/environments/development.rb

```
JumboSIP::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  module Devise
    module LdapAdapter
      def self.valid_credentials?(login, password)
        return true
      end
    end
  end

  config.cache_store = :memory_store

  config.log_level = :debug

  config.assets.compile = true

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  [..etc]

  # ------------------------------------
  # Application-specific configuration
  # ------------------------------------

  # use active directory auythentication (only for production)
  config.x.use_ad_auth = false
 # Enable to create cockpit cache files
  config.x.cockpit_cache_enabled = false
```

config/initializers/scheduler.rb

```
if Rails.configuration.x.cockpit_cache_enabled
      Rails.logger.info 'Initializing Cockpit Cache Scheduler'
      puts 'Initializing Cockpit Cache Scheduler'
```

The code in the if is reached while it should not.
Debug inspection shows that

```
Rails.configuration.x.cockpit_cache_enabled evaluates to Empty ActiveSupport:OrderedOptions. 
Rails.configuration.x is of type CustomConfiguration::Configuration
```

I checked I am actually in development environment.

Any clue as to why this happens? Any conflicts with other gems?
If I uses orderedoptions outside this gem, behaviour is as expected

Answer (score 1):

It's two months delayed, but I ran into the same issue. The custom_configuration gem expects the options to be namespaced under another hash. Instead of:

```
config.x.cockpit_cache_enabled = false
```

try:

```
config.x.cockpit.cache_enabled = false
```

Now you should be able to access the value with:

```
Rails.configuration.x.cockpit.cache_enabled
```